# Function to get the original size of a featured image - full size

Tags: wordpress, function, size, thumbnails, custom-post-type

I need to know de original size of an uploaded image.

I have tried `get_option( 'thumbnail_size_w' )` and `get_option( 'thumbnail_size_h' )` and i get 150x150 but cant find the way to get the original size of this image instead of the thumbnail image.

I'm searching something like this `get_option( 'full_size_w' )` and `get_option( 'full_size_h' )` but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the image source with size 'full'. The 'source' array contains the dimensions of the image size retrieved.

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full' );
var_dump($src[1]); // image width
var_dump($src[2]); // image height
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/ for more information.

Comment: This works perfect, @jrswgtr ... and was so simple to understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Tamplix you're welcome! Will you please consider upvoting and marking answer as correct? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
the_post_thumbnail('full');         // Original image
```

You can use core WordPress functions to get different sizes of image.

```
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');    // Thumbnail (default 150px x 150px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium');       // Medium  (default 300px x 300px max)
the_post_thumbnail('medium_large'); // Medium Large (default 768px x 0( automatic height by ratio) max ) since WP version 4.4
the_post_thumbnail('large');        // Large (default 640px x 640px max)
```